# No consigo sacar la informacion del PHP con Jquery

Tags: javascript, php

Me gustaria que se imprimieran por pantalla  los datos del php

Intento conectar el php con Jquery y atraves del Jquery intentar imprimirlo por pantalla con el hmtl

este es mi html

```
<body>

      <div id="titulo"></div>
      <input type="number" id="indice"><br>
      <p id="nombre">
        
      </p>
      <p id="edad"> 

      </p>
      <p id="estudios">

      </p>
</body>
```

Mi Javascript

El console.log no me saca tampoco la informacion solo me saca undefined

```
function sacard(datos, salida){
    if(salida == "success"){
        persona=JSON.parse(datos);

        $("#nombre").text(persona.nombre);
        $("#edad").text(persona.edad);
        $("#estudios").text(persona.estudios);

        console.log(persona.nombre);
    }
}
```

y mi php

```
<?php

$integrantes=[
    ['nombre' => 'Adrián',
     'edad' => 19,
     'estudios' => 'Grado superior'
    ],

    ['nombre' => 'Álvaro',
     'edad' => 14,
     'estudios' => 'Tercero de la ESO'
    ],
];

echo json_encode($integrantes);
```

Comment: A simple vista, tu `PHP` devuelve un arreglo de "personas", por lo que en `JS` deberias recorrer dicho arreglo. Es decir `persona=JSON.parse(datos);` no es una persona es un arreglo de personas.

Comment: haz intentado hacer `console.log(datos)` para saber que la consulta al menos si se está ejecutando bien y que el servidor si está respondiendo al menos algo? Deberías agregar tambien la manera en la que consultas el servidor... también podría haber un error por ahi.

Answer (score 0):

Tal como te han indicado en los comentarios, esto devuelve un array (arreglo o matriz segun se denomina en distintos lugares) de personas, no una sola persona:

```javascript
persona=JSON.parse(datos);
```

por lo tanto, lo que necesitas para sacar sus datos es recorrerlo mediante un bucle, por ejemplo, así:

```javascript
function sacard(datos, salida){
    if(salida == "success"){
        persona=JSON.parse(datos);
        for(i=0; i<persona.length; i++) {
            console.log(persona[i].nombre);
        }
    }
}
```

El bucle no tiene misterio: Empieza asignando la variable `i` un valor numérico de 0, y mientras se cumpla la condición de que `i` es menor que el número de elementos del array `persona` (que sabemos gracias a la propiedad `.length`) se ejecutará su contenido, y finalizará incrementando en 1 el valor de `i` para la siguiente iteración.

Te dejo un snippet de ejemplo:

```js
datos = `[{"nombre":"Adri\u00e1n","edad":19,"estudios":"Grado superior"},{"nombre":"\u00c1lvaro","edad":14,"estudios":"Tercero de la ESO"}]`

function sacard(datos, salida){
    if(salida == "success"){
        persona=JSON.parse(datos);
        for(i=0; i<persona.length; i++) {
            console.log(persona[i].nombre);
        }
    }
}

sacard(datos, "success")
```

Partiendo de eso, realiza las modificaciones y asignaciones que creas convenientes para adaptarlo a tu salida HTML.